# MUI Textfield: Difference between InputProps disabled vs disabled

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, textfield

In MUI textfield, you can disable it with different ways:

1. By passing the `disabled` prop directly
2. By passing the `InputProps: {{ disabled: true }}`
3. By passing the `inputProps: {{ disabled: true }}`

While the 3rd one disables the input field only whereas the 1st and the 2nd disable the whole `TextField` component.

But, what is the difference between the 1st and the 2nd and which one should be used to disable the textfield?
If `aria-disabled` needs to be applied to a textfield, should it be set in `inputProps` or `InputProps` as ARIA properties are not available directly?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Referring to the documentation description on the `InputProps`.
[image]

Here is my understanding of the difference between the 1st and 2nd

`disabled` on `Textfied` takes effect on the component directly. The colors of the `label` and `helpText` are lighter than that of the 2nd one.

[image]

`disabled` on `Textfied.InputProps` will be passed to the inner Input component which is also an MUI component.

[image]